# com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using Android Development Toolkit Version: 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 and library Android 4.0.3

After compilations the emulator starts and after few minutes it fails to launch.

When i try to launch got the below message from console

```
[2012-02-10 15:48:41 - MyHelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-02-10 15:48:41 - MyHelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-02-10 15:50:15 - MyHelloAndroid] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-02-10 15:50:15 - MyHelloAndroid] Uploading MyHelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-02-10 15:50:15 - MyHelloAndroid] Installing MyHelloAndroid.apk...
[2012-02-10 15:50:55 - MyHelloAndroid] Success!
[2012-02-10 15:50:55 - MyHelloAndroid] Failed to install MyHelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
[2012-02-10 15:50:55 - MyHelloAndroid] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
[2012-02-10 15:50:55 - MyHelloAndroid] Launch canceled!
```

can any one help me out on this.

Answer (score 5):

It has created your program as an app in the emulator. So after this error comes you should directly go to the emulator and check for your app there and run it.

Regards: Hayk Nahapetyan