# Android adb install unsuccessful (facebook integration, Ubuntu)

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, installation, adb

I have installed android-SDK (not ADT bundle - actually I don't know its purpose),
Eclipse, added ADT plugin into Eclipse and added several virtual devices.

According to the manual on fb dev. site, I was trying to install facebook with this command:

```
./adb install ~/facebook-android-sdk-3.5/bin/FBAndroid-3.5.apk
```

But it turned back this error:

```
error: device not found
```

I also managed to import android library from facebook-sdk and attempted to launch an example file. The result:

```
Failed to install HelloFacebookSample.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
[2013-08-28 17:46:37 - HelloFacebookSample] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: 
device not found
[2013-08-28 17:46:37 - HelloFacebookSample] Launch canceled!
```

Any idea what have I missed?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224454/com-android-ddmlib-installexception-eof

Answer (score 0):

Must be one problem of following:

1. Phone usb drivers not installed.
2. You not connected.
3. USB Debugging not enabled in phone.
4. PC or phone USB port problem.

Comment: Well, what do you suggest to do?